# Upgrade Webkit PyGTK Libraries

Tags: python, pygtk, webkit

I'm developing a PyGTK-HTML5 Application (Using Quickly), but the webkit libraries (WebView) are a bit old, at least for using some of the latest HTML5 APIs (like IndexedDB) is it possible to upgrade the libraries? and if so, when I package the app, will it have that specific library that I just upgraded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

No it's probably not worth it for redistribution.

If you did manually update your pygi+webkit you would have to shove that in a ppa and depend on your own packaged version of WebKit in order to "send" the functionality to other users.

You would run the risk of breaking other things that depend on the current version in repo, which is why there is a version freeze on distribution release.

Comment: Thank you very much, then I'll use some other alternative (:

Comment: Even with a newer version of WebKit, it likely won't solve the issue of missing APIs from the GIR APIs. There are a lot of APIs in WebKit-GTK+ which are not introspected. Also, PyGTK is no longer the recommended way to develop applications. One should use PyGI for everything GTK+ related in Python.

Comment: @dobey - Unless you want it to work on Windows.  One guy cross-compiled some bits and pieces, but it was some time ago.

Comment: If you want it to work on Windows too, then you should probably use Qt instead of GTK+. Using WebKit-GTK+ on Windows is very non-trivial.

Comment: @dobey http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2011/01/conservative-all-in-one-pygtk-installer.html

Comment: @dobey I'm using PyGI (quickly app), I tought it was PyGtK but AbrahamVanHelpsing illustrated me (: , thanks though.